# Variable type in the stream

Tags: c++

I need to compare that the value in stream has the same type as variable.
How can I recognize the type of data which is sent in the stream to variable? For example "cin".

```
try{
if(/*condition for cin*/)throw string("exception occur");
//rest code in try block
}
catch(string exception){
std::cerr << exception;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would help if you could provide some details.  Where is this "stream" coming from?  Can you post a code snippet indicating how you are processing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the stream state after extracting a value from it:

```
int value;
if (cin >> value) {
  // value is set now
} else {
  // oops, bad input
}
```